# Dynamic URLs PHP-HTML

Tags: php, html

I want to reuse HTML content dynamically using PHP. In this case, I have index.php from where I call the navigation menu using `<?php include(PHP_PATH . '/navigation.php'); ?>` and the menu is displayed. The problem is that the links of the menu don't work.Apparently, I am defining the WWW_ROOT wrongly but I can't figure it out why.

**Navigation menu**

```
    <li class="active">
        <a href="<?php echo WWW_ROOT . '/index.php'; ?>">
            <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt" style="opacity:0.4;"></i>
            <p>Dashboard</p>
        </a>
    </li>
```

**initialize.php First attempt**

```
    <?php
      define("PHP_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
      define("WWW_ROOT", '');

    ?>
```

The folder  where the project is being developed is called "lpweb", so I tried the following, which does not work either:

**initialize.php Second attempt**

```
<?php
    define("PHP_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
    $public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/lpweb');
    $doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $lpweb_end);
    define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);
?>
```

Comment: You have a typo here $doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $lpweb_end); Are you misusing $lpweb_end instead of $public_end ?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed Thanks, it works now, but the problem is that is linking to the "localhost" instead of "localhost/lpweb", so the pages are not found. Any idea how can I solve it?

Comment: I have added an answer. Check it out

Comment: Don't know exactly how to do that. Thanks for your help, keep trying.

Comment: Did you use my define("WWW_ROOT",rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/')); echo WWW_ROOT; What did you get on the screen?

Comment: Yes, I get 404 (Not Found) in the CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
define("WWW_ROOT",rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/'));
```

Comment: What do you get when you echo WWW_ROOT; ?

Comment: The objects are not found. The problem is that the navigation menu redirects me to localhost/index.php instead of localhost/lpweb/index.php. It looks like it skips one level and go to localhost, but it should go to lpweb.

Comment: could you put a print_r($_SERVER) and add it to the OP ? I will be easy to understand your problem. What's the URL you type on the browser?